# Unable to check checkbox inside second loop

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngfor

I want to list years with some months you can check.
The problem I'm facing is that I'm unable to actually check a checkbox.
In another variant I tried setting `checked` in the code behind but the UI would stay unchecked.

My guess is, it has something to do with the 2 loops inside each other but I'm not how to resolve this.

**Model**

```
export class YearsAndMonths {
  public year: number;
  public months: Month[] = [
    { name: "January", numeric: 1, checked: false },
...
  ]
}

export class Month {
  public name: string;
  public checked: boolean;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form *ngIf="years">
  <section *ngFor="let year of years; let y = index">
    <div class="row">
      <strong>{{year.year}}</strong>
    </div>

    <mat-checkbox name='ym{{y}}{{i}}' *ngFor="let month of year.months; let i = index; trackBy: trackByIdx">
      {{month.name}}
    </mat-checkbox>
  </section>
</form>
```

**HTML** *variant*

```
<mat-checkbox *ngFor="let month of year.months; let i = index; trackBy: trackByIdx"
              class="row" name='ym{{y}}{{i}}' [checked]="month.checked" (change)="onMonthChanged(month)">
  {{month.name}}    
</mat-checkbox>
```

**Component**

```
  @Input() years: YearsAndMonths[];
  trackByIdx(index: number, obj: any): any {
    return index;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I added the `[trackByIdx][1]` on each loop (in my case the years)... this made it work.

```
<form *ngIf="years">
  <section *ngFor="let year of years; let y = indexOfYears; trackBy: trackByIdx">
    <div class="row">
      <strong>{{year.year}}</strong>
    </div>
    <!--<div *ngFor="let month of year.months; let i = index; trackBy: trackByIdx" class="form-check row">
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" [checked]="month.checked" (change)="onMonthChanged(month)" name='ym{{y}}{{i}}'>
      <label class="form-check-label">{{month.name}}</label>
    </div>-->

    <mat-checkbox *ngFor="let month of year.months; let i = indexOfMonths; trackBy: trackByIdx"
                  class="row" name='ym{{y}}{{i}}' [checked]="month.checked" (change)="onMonthChanged(month)">
      {{month.name}}    
    </mat-checkbox>

  </section>
</form>
```